# Optimize JSonArray for Loop

Tags: java, android, json

Today, I'm trying to optimize my JSONArray regarding [android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html). I was supposed to optimize it but there is error message coming out.

```
JSONArray infojson = json.getJSONArray("getInfo");          
for(int i=0;i < infojson.length();i++){                                     
    JSONObject e = infojson.getJSONObject(i);
    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put(MYNAME, e.getString("uname"));
    hm.put(MYAGE, e.getString("uage"));
}
```

And I've optimized above coding as follow

```
JSONArray infojson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("getInfo");
for (Object o : infojson ) {
    JSONObject jsonLineItem = (JSONObject) o;
    String myname = jsonLineItem.getString("uname");
    String myage = jsonLineItem.getString("uage");
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error message occuring on **"infojson ) {"**

**Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use JSONArray with the that syntax as it doesn't implement [Iterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. As a side note, the micro performance improvement you get probably won't affect your application performance as JSON results that are returned from the WebService are typically not large in size.

Comment: My JSON is about 650.000 bytes. Does it also count as `not large`?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because `JSONArray` doesn't implement the `Iterable` `interface`.

In short, there's no clean way to solve this; you'd have to serialize the `JSONObjects` into your custom class.

To save you time though, using `(Object one: all) over (i=0; i < all.getLength(); i++)` won't give you any runtime improvements.

Just stick to the normal for loop.