# Should I be able to use a Java for-each with type Object?

Tags: java, object, foreach, loops, arrays

I have an instance of a `JSONArray` and I was just curious if I could use a for-each construct to work with each element in sequence.  So I tried:

```
for( Object jsonObj: jsonArray ) {
  System.out.println("JSONArray element: '" + ((JSONObject)jsonObj).toString() + "'");
}
```

To my surprise it worked. I thought I'd need to be working with classes that implement Iterable.

So if you can answer my initial question (using for-each on `JSONArray`), that's great.  Also:

- 2nd question: Why is it working?
- 3rd question: Should I be leery of actually using this in shipping code?

Thanks all!

Comment: JsonArray *is* iterable. The fact that you're implicitly casting each item returned by the iterator to `Object` really has no bearing. And *why* would you do this, would be the question I'd ask ...

Comment: @BrianRoach where does it say it in the docs?

Comment: @Christian - What docs?  *It compiles*, therefore it's implementing `Iterable`.

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341823/optimize-jsonarray-for-loop. Varying result?

Comment: Sorry - that's a typo in my original comment. I meant to start it with `jsonArray` (his variable name) - I have no idea what class that is actually an instance of but if his code compiles and runs then it's implementing `Iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might know, the for each loop [only works for Iterables and arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

The original json.org implementation of JSONArray [doesn't implement iterable](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html), but the [Gson implementation does](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), as pointed out by @Quirim and @BrianRoach.

There was an [intend to implement it](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/pull/77) in the json.org version but at the end they didn't.

So to answer your 3 questions:

1. You have to be using a Gson or similar implementation of
   JsonArray that implements iterable.
2. Because JsonArray is Iterable.
3. No, you shouldn't.

Comment: [JsonArray](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) This implementation shows that it is iterable. I don't know that, this implementation is relevant now, or it is another that is used.

Comment: That's the JsonArray of Gson right? I took the json.org implementation.

Comment: I really have no idea what he's using. The ancient crufty `org.json.JSONArray` isn't iterable in any version that I know of, but I wouldn't use it anyway. The PR you cite the guy closed it without merging saying he doesn't want that so it's still compatible with 1.4. Whatever he's using though has to implement `Iterable` or it simply wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yes, you are right, on the official json.org there isn't any information about Iterable interface.

Comment: Yeah, it was moved to github then any number people have cloned / copied / modified it. It's conceivable there's a version out there that implemented Iterable but who knows where the OP got it from.

Comment: Ah yes.  Well, I'm not using GSON, but I am using this:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.web2mobile.json.help%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fjson%2Fjava%2FJSONArray.html

Comment: @user2100752 well, if you like the answer you can accept it. Also, I think you should check the javadocs before posting the question. I thought that you were using the original implementation.

Comment: Which ... tells you on that page that it's iterable. You're using some ancient library that isn't using Generics and is extending `ArrayList` which is why you have to explicitly cast from `Object`

Answer (score 0):

[The for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) syntax was introduced in java 1.5. It's aim is to clean your code from evident things like iterators, also it cuts off some error possiblity.

This kind of loop statement only works on `Iterable` classes, to answear your question, it is because `JsonArray` is implement `Iterable` interface.

Regarding to your code, I think it also works, if you exactly sais `jsonObj` is the type of `JSONObject`, and it isn't just an `Object`. In this way you can elliminate the error prone type casting from the body of your loop.

Comment: But I cannot, sir.  JSONArrays don't contain JSONObjects,  they contain Objects.  

Just to be certain, I tried again.  Changing Object to JSONObject results in:
**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to JSONObject**

And I don't see anything in the JSONArray class as implementing Iterable:

[link](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: @user2100752 - We don't have ESP, we have no idea what library you're using. Whatever it is, it isn't what you link to above or your code *would not compile* never mind run.

Comment: @Brian: You should reconsider ESP, it would really make things more efficient. ;)  Also, in this project I inherited I assumed it was the standard JSON library, my bad.  Question answered.  Thanks.